# Displaying custom template for specific categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a "Program" category and this category have childs. (For example Program -> Improving speed )

I want to display custom category template for childs of Program category.

I found that : 
WordPress have template_include function that executes immediately before WordPress includes the predetermined template file. This can be used to override WordPress's default template behavior.

So I try to use this code in my functions.php file :

```
function wpse_template_check( $template ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        // Get category information
        $cat = get_query_var( 'cat' ); 
        // read the category parent 
        $parent_category = $cat->category_parent;

        //I want to load this template
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'category-program.php' ) );

        //Program category have ID=43 so I check here if parent category = program 
        if ( ($parent_category) == 43) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_template_check' );
```

But it did not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

The issue here is that `get_query_var( 'cat' )` returns the current category ID. If you had debug turned on, you would have seen the following notice

> NOTICE Error: [8] Trying to get property of non-object

You should replace `get_query_var( 'cat' )` with `get_queried_object()` which will get the queried object object.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. 

By the way I modified this code : 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173607/how-to-show-wordpress-parent-and-child-category-different-page/180247?noredirect=1#comment263244_180247 

And there Robert uses locate_template with array, and his code works. So I don't think if there is an issue with that line of code.

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy. :-)